# How to keep logged in symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have my Login form, LoginForm.class.php:

```
public function configure()
{
$this->setWidgets(array(
  'username' => new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('style' => 'width:130px;')), 
  'password' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('style' => 'width:130px;'))
));

$this->setValidators(array(
  'username' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => TRUE), array('required' => 'Please provide your username.')), 
  'password' => new sfValidatorString(array('required' => TRUE), array('required' => 'Please provide your password.'))
));


$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'checkUserdata'))));    
$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('user[%s]');

}
public function checkUserdata($validator, $values) 
{  

if ($values['username'] && $values['password'])
{           

    $currUser = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('user');
    $oUser = Doctrine_Core::getTable('user')->findOneByUsernameAndPassword($values['username'], md5($values['password']));

    if($oUser)
    {
        if($oUser->getSuspend() == 0)
        {
            //Previous credentials are removed

            if(sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
            {
                sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->removeNamespace('ns_user');
                sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAuthenticated(false);
                sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->clearCredentials();
            }

            //This new user is authenticated
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAuthenticated(true);

            //All info about the user is stored into a session variable
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute('id', $oUser->getId(), 'ns_user');
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute('username', $oUser->getUsername(), 'ns_user');
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute('name', $oUser->getName(), 'ns_user');
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->setAttribute('type', $oUser->getType(), 'ns_user');

            //credentials are set
            sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->addCredential('user');
        }
        else
        {
            throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'This user is suspended. Please activate before login.');

        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new sfValidatorError($validator, 'Wrong username or password.');
    }
}

return $values;
}
```

And in loginActions:

```
public function executeIndex(sfRequest $request)
{
$this->setTitle('Authentication');
$this->form = new LoginForm(); //A new form object is created

if($request->isMethod('post')) //It checks if it comes from Post
{
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('user'));

    $user = $request->getParameter('user');

    if($this->form->isValid()) //If form validation is ok
    { 
        if(($user['username'] == "admin" && $user['password'] == "admin") || $this->getUser()->getAttribute('type','','ns_user') == 'admin')
            return $this->redirect('admin/index');
        else
            return $this->redirect('home/index');
    }
}
}


public function executeLogout($request)
{
//Authentication data is removed
if($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
{
    $this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->removeNamespace('ns_user');
    $this->getUser()->setAuthenticated(false);
    $this->getUser()->clearCredentials();
}

return $this->redirect('login/index');
}
```

If the login session is expired and I press any button an exception is displayed - Error 404. 
How to keep logged in after the session is expired?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to `apps/[your_application_name]/[your_module_name]`, where you should see actions folder and template folder. Then add folder named `config` (if there isn't one) inside module folder (parallel with actions folder and template folder), and add a file named `security.yml` inside config folder.

add this following code inside security.yml file to disable authentication in module level:

```
all:
  is_secure: false
```

There is also config folder inside your `apps/[your_application_name]` folder, in case you want to remove authentication for your application level, add this following code in the security yml in `apps/[your_application_name]/config/security.yml`

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```